# Limit of quotient of summations involving special binomial coefficients

Tags: limits, binomial-coefficients

Find the limit, when $n$ tends to infinity, of
$$
  \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n}{2k}3^k}
       {\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{2k+1}3^k}
$$

Please Help Me to solve the problem given and i have no idea to do since  i have done such this  one and need help also many hint of course.

Comment: ${1 \over \,\sqrt{\,3\,}\,}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n}{2k}3^k-\sqrt3\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{2k+1}3^k=(\sqrt3-1)^{2n}
$$
and
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n}{2k}3^k+\sqrt3\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{2k+1}3^k=(\sqrt3+1)^{2n}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n}{2k}3^k}{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{2k+1}3^k}
&=\sqrt3\,\frac{(\sqrt3+1)^{2n}+(\sqrt3-1)^{2n}}{(\sqrt3+1)^{2n}-(\sqrt3-1)^{2n}}\\
&=\sqrt3\,\frac{1+\left(\frac{\sqrt3-1}{\sqrt3+1}\right)^{2n}}{1-\left(\frac{\sqrt3-1}{\sqrt3+1}\right)^{2n}}
\end{align}
$$
Taking the limit is pretty simple.

Comment: but how to know that the solution is $\sqrt[2]{3}$ you havent proved thatthe fractional part is 1 dont you?

Comment: but how to know that the solution is $\sqrt[2]{3}$ you havent proved thatthe fractional part is 1 dont you?

Comment: @Deddy: Do you see that see that $\left|\frac{\sqrt3-1}{\sqrt3+1}\right|\lt1$? What happens when you raise such a number to a high power?

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n}{2k}3^k=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n}{2k}(\sqrt3)^{2k}$

and $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{2k+1}3^k=\dfrac{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{2k+1}(\sqrt3)^{2k+1}}{\sqrt3}$

Use $(1+x)^{2n}+(1-x)^{2n}=\cdots$ and $(1+x)^{2n}-(1-x)^{2n}=\cdots$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You can use that for any $m$, and $i\in\{0,1\}$ one has
$$
  \sum_{k\equiv i\pmod2}\binom mkX^k
 =\frac12\sum_k(1^k+(-1)^{k+i})\binom mkX^k
 =\frac12((1+X)^m+(-1)^i(1-X)^m),
$$
and apply this with $m=2n$ and $X=\sqrt3$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
${\ds{\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}}\ {\ds{\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{n}\ {2n \choose 2k}3^{k}}\over
  \ds{\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{n - 1}\ {2n \choose 2k + 1}3^{k}}}: \ {\large ?}}$.

---

The expression $\ds{{2n \choose 2k + s}3^{k}}$, with
$\ds{s = 0, 1}$, is 'highly concentrated' around
$\ds{\tilde{k}_{s} = {6n - 3s - \root{3} s \over 2\pars{3 + \root{3}}}}$ when
$\ds{n \gg 1}$such that
$$
\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{n - s}{2n \choose 2k + s}3^{k}
\sim {2n \choose 2\tilde{k}_{s} + s }3^{\tilde{k}_{s}}
\int_{0}^{n - s}
\exp\pars{-\,{\bracks{k - \tilde{k}_{s}}^{2} \over 2\sigma^{2}}}\,\dd k\,,
\qquad\sigma\equiv{\root{3} \over 2\root{3 + 2\root{3}}}\,n^{1/2}
$$

---

Then,
\begin{align}
{\ds{\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{n}\ {2n \choose 2k}3^{k}}\over
 \ds{\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{n - 1}\ {2n \choose 2k + 1}3^{k}}}
\sim{\ds{2n \choose 2\tilde{k}_{0}}3^{\tilde{k}_{0}} \over \ds{2n \choose 2\tilde{k}_{1} + 1}3^{\tilde{k}_{1}}}
=3^{\tilde{k}_{0} - \tilde{k}_{1}}=\root{3}
\qquad n \gg 1
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}\color{#66f}{\large\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\
{\ds{\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{n}\ {2n \choose 2k}3^{k}}\over
 \ds{\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{n - 1}\ {2n \choose 2k + 1}3^{k}}}}
=\color{#66f}{\large\root{3}}
\end{align}